# Opening a text file from Hyperlink in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, text

I am trying to open a text file in a separate window from a hyperlink. This is what I have:

```
#include "aboutdialog.h"
#include "ui_aboutdialog.h"

aboutdialog::aboutdialog(QWidget *parent) :
QDialog(parent),
ui(new Ui::aboutdialog)
 {
   ui->setupUi(this);
   this->setFixedSize(550,380);
 }

 aboutdialog::~aboutdialog()
 {
 delete ui;
 }

 void aboutdialog::on_pushButton_clicked()
 {
 close();
 }


 // Open Qt Libraries Terms and Conditions
 void aboutdialog::on_label_6_linkActivated(const QString &link)
 {

 QString fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(
           this,
           tr("Qt libraries Terms and Conditions"),
           "",
           tr("Text Files (/LICENSE.LGPL)"));
 if(!fileName.isEmpty())
  {
   QFile file(fileName);
   if(file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
   {
       file.readAll();
    }
  }
}
```

It tells me:

```
ShellExecute 'LICENSE.LGPL' failed (error 2)
```

Can someone point to a problem?

Comment: Where does the URL come into play? I only see an ordinary file dialog here. Also where is shell execute called? I have the impression your code sample is incomplete.

Comment: Hi. Yes, it is a linkActivated slot for QLabel. The full code is like this:

Comment: Sorry. Cannot put code here. Let me edit the original text

Comment: This is a label with LinksAccessibleByMouse enabled that reads as follows: <html><head/><body><p><a href="LICENSE.LGPL"><span style=" text-decoration: underline; color:#0000ff;">Qt libraries Terms and Conditions</span></a></p></body></html>

Comment: What is the file dialog supposed to do?

Comment: Hi. I have a plain text file (LICENSE.LGPL). I wanted to open this text file using a default text editor by clicking on the hyperlink. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your UI file has a QLabel with the link, and this QLabel has `openExternalLinks` property set to true.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

```
QString fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(
                                this,
                                tr("Qt libraries Terms and Conditions"),
                                "/LICENSE.lgpl",
                                tr("LICENSE (*.lgpl);;All Files (*)")
                                );
```

Comment: Nope, sorry. I have made a temporary solution: created a dialog box with the license text in it and triggered the hyperlink to open the dialog instead. I would prefer opening the text in a text editor.